# Removing 1 of 2 Exchange servers

Tags: windows-server-2008, exchange

I'm new in a company and I'm still learning exchange as this is the first time, I'm managing a system. I have been tasked to remove one of two 2010 exchange servers from my environment which are both running on Windows 2008r2 and are virtual servers. Lets call them EXVM01 and EXVM02.

I do not know the technical name of how the exchange servers are setup, I believe it is in a HA (High availability). The servers work independently as they both have their own mail databases.

I have done extensive research and I have migrated all the users from databases on EXVM02 to databases on EXVM01. My boss then shutdown EXVM02 however when I browse EXVM01 I can see there are still some connections to EXVM02.

My questions is how can I remove all EXVM02 configurations on EXVM01 and what is the correct way of removing the exchange server?

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of considerations that are beyond the scope of your question (making sure there are no orphaned public folders, for example) but, ultimately, you need to be doing a clean and orderly uninstall of Exchange from the EXVM02 server computer. Hopefully your boss didn't delete the VM but, rather, just powered it off.

Comment: Would this remove the configurations on EXVM01 that link to EXVM02?

Also would you happen to know the technical name of how my exchange servers are configured

Comment: @user141432 - Unfortunately, I'd need a lot more information to tell you anything much more definitive than I already have.